# Syntax Highlighter for Java

Tags: feature-request, syntax-highlighting

It seems the syntax highlighter is not able to handle Java.

Any idea how to help fix this?

A sample code is below, and [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30046376/184201) and [links2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30051686/184201) in stackoverflow.

```
try (Statement stmt = con.createStatement()) {
    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);

    while (rs.next()) {
        String coffeeName = rs.getString("COF_NAME");
        int supplierID = rs.getInt("SUP_ID");
        float price = rs.getFloat("PRICE");
        int sales = rs.getInt("SALES");
        int total = rs.getInt("TOTAL");

        System.out.println(coffeeName + ", " + supplierID + ", " + 
                           price + ", " + sales + ", " + total);
    }
}
```

EDIT: Well, it seems syntax highlighter doesn't work in stackexchange, but in stackoverlow instead.

For the same case: most of the times, it doesn't work, e.g.

[image: Without Highlighter]

And now it does

[image: With Highlighter]

Comment: What code is wrongly formatted?

Comment: Actually, I visited link1 now, and it is fine, although I have it in another window as not highlighted!!!!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Code formatting is based on the language. The language is determined from the tag on the question.

In this case, the question didn't have the java tag. [Once added](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/30034553/revisions), it recognized the language and the syntax highlighting works.

Or add the language in the post by putting this in:

```
<!-- language: lang-java -->
```

---

```java
try (Statement stmt = con.createStatement()) {
    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);

    while (rs.next()) {
        String coffeeName = rs.getString("COF_NAME");
        int supplierID = rs.getInt("SUP_ID");
        float price = rs.getFloat("PRICE");
        int sales = rs.getInt("SALES");
        int total = rs.getInt("TOTAL");

        System.out.println(coffeeName + ", " + supplierID + ", " + 
                           price + ", " + sales + ", " + total);
    }
}
```